# Maintain selected radio button item on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, random, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I want to populate a RadioButtonList with 5 values from a database in a random order.

So I've tried to store the 5 values in Session objects and then used the following code to add the values to the RadioButtonList (rblQuestions) randomly:

```
    Random ran = new Random();
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).OrderBy(i => ran.Next()).ToList();

    List<ListItem> ans = new List<ListItem>();
    ans.Add(new ListItem(Session["Value1"].ToString(), "y"));
    ans.Add(new ListItem(Session["Value2"].ToString(), "n"));
    ans.Add(new ListItem(Session["Value3"].ToString(), "n"));
    ans.Add(new ListItem(Session["Value4"].ToString(), "n"));
    ans.Add(new ListItem(Session["Value5"].ToString(), "n"));

    foreach (int num in numbers)
    {
        rblQuestions.Items.Add(ans[num - 1]);
    }
```

This works great.  However, when I click on another button on the same form, the selected item in the list changes randomly.  Why is this and how can I avoid this?

[EDIT to include code.]

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnGetQuestion" runat="server" Text="Get Question" OnClick="btnGetQuestion_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblQuestions" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCheck" runat="server" Text="Check Answer" OnClick="btnCheck_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class questions : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void btnGetQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getRandomQuestion();
}

protected void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void getRandomQuestion()
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            lblQuestion.Text = reader["question"].ToString();
            Session["Answer1"] = reader["answer1"].ToString();
            Session["Answer2"] = reader["answer2"].ToString();
            Session["Answer3"] = reader["answer3"].ToString();
            Session["Answer4"] = reader["answer4"].ToString();
            Session["Answer5"] = reader["answer5"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "(no questions found)";
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        lblError.Text = "Database connection error - failed to insert record.";
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    Random ran = new Random();
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).OrderBy(i => ran.Next()).ToList();

    List<ListItem> ans = new List<ListItem>();
    ans.Add(new ListItem(Session["Answer1"].ToString(), "y"));
    ans.Add(new ListItem(Session["Answer2"].ToString(), "n"));
    ans.Add(new ListItem(Session["Answer3"].ToString(), "n"));
    ans.Add(new ListItem(Session["Answer4"].ToString(), "n"));
    ans.Add(new ListItem(Session["Answer5"].ToString(), "n"));

    foreach (int num in numbers)
    {
        rblQuestions.Items.Add(ans[num - 1]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: On which event you have write this code

Comment: write a function to populate radio button and call that function in !Postback in page load. I hope it would solve your problem.

Comment: @Sain I have 2 buttons.  I want to populate the RadioButtonList on Button1_Click so Button1_Click contains accessing the databases, retrieving the values and then the code above.  However, when Button2 is clicked, the selected radio button item changes randomly but I want the radio button item selected to remain the same.

Comment: Can you show your complete code

Comment: @SainPradeep I have included it in the original post.